# Was ist das deutsche Wort für „rekrutieren“?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, loanword

> Die Armee rekrutiert viele Jugendliche im Jahre.
>
> The Army recruits many teenagers a year.

Die einzigen Verben, die mir einfallen, sind *anwerben* oder *werben*. *Rekrutieren* ist ein Fremdwort.

Comment: Um welche Art von Armee geht es – z.B. mit oder ohne Wehrpflicht? Früher wurden Armeen bzw. Rekruten _ausgehoben_, aber das kann man bspw. auf die Bundeswehr nicht mehr ernsthaft anwenden. [Jugendliche und Teenager](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jugend#Definitionen_der_.E2.80.9EJugend.E2.80.9C) ist auch nicht deckungsgleich – in Deutschland muss man mindestens 18 (ausnahmsweise auch 17) Jahre alt sein, um den „Dienst an der Waffe“ antreten zu dürfen (früher auch müssen), daher trifft es _junge Erwachsene_ besser, es sei denn es geht um die Werbung (nicht Anwerbung) bei Jüngeren (15/16).

Comment: Das deutsche Wort für _rekrutieren_ lautete _rekrutieren_.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

*Rekrutieren* ist seit Jahrhunderten normaler Bestandteil der deutschen Sprache und befindet sich im Grenzbereich zwischen Fremdwort und Lehnwort. Wie bei vielen anderen Wörtern lateinischen oder romanischen Ursprungs gibt es hier überhaupt keinen Grund, das Wort zu vermeiden.

Ungefähr zur Zeit der Romantik, z.T. aber auch noch später, gab es starke Bestrebungen, den lateinischen und romanischen Einfluss im Deutschen zu reduzieren. Dazu wurden viele rein germanische Ersetzungen erfunden, von denen manche erfolgreich waren (Auto fahren statt chauffieren, Regenschirm statt Paraplui), manche nur beschränkt (Stelldichein statt Rendezvous, Behörde statt Amt) und manche gar nicht und wohl von vorne herein nicht ganz ernst gemeint (Gesichtserker statt Nase). Vor allem im Umfeld von Behörden ist häufig noch heute der lateinische oder romanische Ausdruck der allgemein verständliche und umgangssprachliche, während der germanische bürokratisch klingt.

Der Unterschied zwischen *anwerben* und *rekrutieren* ist aber vor allem, dass *anwerben* Freiwilligkeit ausdrückt und betont. *Rekrutieren* ist ein neutraler Ausdruck, der sowohl beim Anwerben als auch beim Wehrdienst und der Zwangsrekrutierung passt.

Das eigentliche Problem im angegebenen Beispielsatz ist *im Jahre*. Das ist keine gute Übersetzung von *a year*, denn es bedeutet wörtlich *in the year*. Besser: "Die Armee rekrutiert jedes Jahr viele Jugendliche."

Comment: _Im Jahr_ ginge schon und wird vor allem bei Zahlenangaben verwendet (_Der durchschnittliche Deutsche trinkt 9,7 Liter reinen Alkohol im Jahr_, _Er fährt dreimal im Jahr nach Zürich_). Das Problem ist das altertümliche Dativ-_e_, das hier überhaupt nicht funktioniert.

Comment: Als weiteren Unterschied zwischen *anwerben* und *rekrutieren* würde ich den implizierten Ausgang des Vorgangs nennen. Wenn ich jemanden *angeworben* habe, war das nicht zwangsläufig erfolgreich, aber wenn ich jemanden *rekrutiert* habe, drückt das schon irgendwie aus, dass die Person nun definitiv mit von der Partie ist.

Answer (score 2):

*Rekrutieren* ist völlig in Ordnung. Es ist ein geläufiges Verb und wird im militärischen Kontext gebraucht. *Anwerben* oder *werben* würde eher im wirtschaftlichen Kontext verwendet. Ein subtiler Unterschied im militärischen Kontext ist, dass man eher davon sprechen würde, dass ein Söldnerunternehmen anwirbt, während man bei einer regulären Armee eher von *rekrutieren* spricht.

Drei Kleinigkeiten gibt es aber mit der Übersetzung.

> … im **Jahre**

"Jahre" ist entweder Plural oder kann in Abkürzung von

> Im Jahre des Herrn XXXX

für ein bestimmtes Jahr verwendet werden, also z.B.

> … im Jahre 2015

Man könnte *im Jahr* auch gegen *pro Jahr* austauschen, wenn man ausdrücken will, das es kontinuierlich viele Jugendliche sind.

Die Armee würde ich immer konkretisieren. Statt also einfach *Armee* zu schreiben, würde ich den Eigennamen der jeweiligen Streitkraft verwenden, also z.B.:

> Das Heer/Die Bundeswehr/US Armed Forces/US Army/British Armed Forces/British Army rekrutiert/rekrutieren viele Jugendliche im Jahr.

Alternativ kann man aber auch ganz allgemein den Begriff *Militär* verwenden, wenn man allgemein über ein Land schreibt. Dann müsste der Satz so aussehen:

> Das Militär rekrutiert pro Jahr viele Jugendliche.

**Anmerkung:** Der Satz ist schon im Englischen vermutlich sachlich falsch, es sei denn, wir reden über Kindersoldaten. In den allermeisten Staaten muss man das Erwachsenenalter erreicht haben, um beim Militär dienen zu dürfen, wobei die Ausbildung mit Zustimmung der Eltern manchmal früher beginnen kann. Dies ist aber zumindest in Deutschland nicht der Regelfall.

Comment: Die alte Dativform hat nichts mit Göttern zu tun.

Comment: @CarstenS Sicher? Fühle Dich frei, zu korrigieren – mit Begründung, natürlich. ;)

Answer (score 1):

- einstellen
- anstellen
- für eine Arbeit verpflichten

sind Alternativen, aber rekruitieren ist ein deutsches Wort, ein deutsches Fremdwort.

> Die Armee verpflichtet viele Jugendliche im Jahr/pro Jahr.

Das passt auch in einer Freiwilligenarmee, da man mit der Unterschrift unter einen Vertrag eine Pflicht eingeht.